# php find same words between sentences

Tags: php, arrays

How to get same words between sentences? here are some cords witch from pdo mysql query.

```
if($q->rowCount()>0){
 foreach($q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $r){
   $t=$r['text'];
   $e=explode(' ',$t);
   //array_intersect();
 }
}
//from $r['text'] query get:
//Israel breaks through the Google Glass ceiling
//Google Glass wearers getting used to curious stares
//Airlines start to look through the Google Glass
```

from these 3 sentences, the same words should be get `Google Glass`, but how to write codes in my pdo mysql query case? thanks

Comment: Can you give some examples ?

Comment: did you try anything yet?

Comment: @Subhanker, example is see the comments, in the foreach, i get 3 sentences, i tried use explode white space to make a 3 arrays, the  how to the `Google Glass`?

Comment: @Lorenzo Marcon, i tired to explode white space to make a 3 arrays, then how to use some function like `array_intersect();` to get the same words?

Comment: If you searching threw posts using search string you can use simple **LIKE** statement from mysql. Can you describe what for and where it can be used? Maybe there is ready answer for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should concatenate all the sentences that you get to a variable and then pass the concatenated variable to explode function, then pass the exploded array to `array_count_values($array)`.

```
Step 1:
```

Concatenate the Sentences to a single variable so you will have

```
$concat = "Israel breaks through the Google Glass ceiling
Google Glass wearers getting used to curious stares
Airlines start to look through the Google Glass";
```

in a single variable.

```
Step 2:
```

pass the $concat to `$array = explode(" ",$concat);`

```
step 3:
```

The exploded variable would be an array you pass that to array_count_values($array);

```
print_r(array_count_values($array));
```

so you would get output like

```
Array
(
   [Google ] => 3
   [Glass] => 2
   etc...
)
```

So the key with count more than 1 are duplicate and you could print those keys easliy

Answer (score 1):

```
$youText= explode(' ',$youText);
$youText= array_flip($youText);
```

check you condition

```
if (isset($youText[$word])){
      doSomething();
  }
```

another way

```
$searchMyWord = $_GET['search'];
    $searchMyWord = preg_quote($searchMyWord);

    if (preg_match("/\b$searchMyWord\b", $input) {
      echo "$input has the word $searchMyWord";
    }
```